# Eigen Iterate over inner iterator in sparse matrix with SIMD

Tags: c++, openmp, eigen, simd

Apply simd over eigen inner iterator of sparse matrix:

```
for(auto i = 0; i < smat.outerSize(); i++){
    #pragma omp simd
    for(SMat::InnerIterator iter(smat,i); it; ++it){
        it.valueRef() = value;
    }
}
```

This does not work due to an error with parenthetical initialization in for loop is incompatible with simd.  Next I try:

```
    SMat::InnerIterator iter(smat,i);
    #pragma omp simd
    for(;it;++it){ // error, declaration or initialization expected

    for(it;it;++it){ // error, declaration or initialization expected
```

Then I google and search the documentation, only to encounter a phrase mentioning that simd is implicit when adding sparse matrices (so I know this is possible, and that somewhere in the templated bowels of eigen, there is a simd loop over the inner vector; but I don't know how to do it).

Next, I check and discover that `Eigen` has only three calls to `omp` in the entire code.  Does this mean that Eigen is reliant only on compiler flags for simd activation?

Finally, I try changing the loop to canonical form (per comment below), and get a different error:

```
for(auto it = typename SMat::InnerIterator(smat,i); it; ++it)

// error: '#pragma omp simd' used with class iteration variable 'it'
```

What is the expected way to trigger or iterate over the inner vector in an `Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>` with simd?

Comment: What version of OpenMP does your compiler support? Anyway, in OpenMP, loops have to be in so-called canonical form, which should in your case look like`for (auto it = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator(smat, i); it != false; ++it)`.

Comment: @DanielLangr thanks man.  It turns out that my code worked on a different setup (double checked in my dev environment), but this canonical format should be correct for all omp versions?

Comment: OpenMP supports iterators from version 3.0 I think (not sure). However, the the iterator must be a _random-access iterator_, which I am not sure `InnerItartor` truly is. I cannot find any documentation for Eigen `InnerIterator`s.

Comment: @DanielLangr yeah, me neither.  and as great as a header library is, it is difficult to follow. thanks for the comment!

Comment: @DanielLangr seems like OMP version 3.1 is supported, according to the GCC docs; now I am getting an "error: pragma omp simd used with class iteration variable", so I will leave this up, since it seems like it should be possible in a c++ matrix library.

Comment: Can you get your compiler to auto-vectorize normally (without OpenMP)?  You shouldn't need `-ffast-math` for pure assignment to auto-vectorize with `gcc -O3` or `clang -O3`, or even `clang -O2` or whatever; `for(...) arr[i] = value` is a common pattern that compilers are typically good at.

Comment: SIMD in Eigen is almost entirely done using compiler intrinsics. Where did you find "that simd is implicit when adding sparse matrices"? (Depends on what you are actually adding, but especially adding two sparse matrices with different non-zero patterns, this sounds difficult.

Comment: `InnerIterator` is indeed not documented at the moment. It could be made compatible to a standard random-access iterator (it lacks some operators like `it-diff`, `--it`, `it-=diff`). For reference, the source is here: https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/0fdf0e56237f92e5/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseCompressedBase.h#SparseCompressedBase.h-135

Comment: @chtz: `InnerIterator` is mentioned in https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html, but that's a tutorial and doesn't detail the type properties.

Comment: @DanielLangr the canonical loop form does **not** allow for `!=` as an operator.

Comment: @PeterCordes regarding the compiler flags: oh ok; this is just a representative sample... I have a bunch of loops through sparse matrices that I would want to ensure are vectorized.  After looking at your comments below though, I will try the pointer conversions out—coming from MKL sparse matrix csr format in C, this is more in line with what I expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to apply `#pragma omp simd` in this context. As per the OpenMP specifications (2.6 Canonical Loop Form), "in the `simd` construct the only random access iterator types that are allowed [...] are pointer types.". The involved iterators are clearly not pointer types. It might be possible to change them to such to allow an OpenMP simd loop, but that would require insight into the implementations and data layout of the involved types.

Comment: If sparse matrices pack their row data contiguously, and have a separate list of which positions of where the non-zero elements go, InnerIterator *could* be just looping over the equivalent of a `std::vector<double>`.  In which case it could be reformulated as an OpenMP-compatible loop.

Comment: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html says there are 4 compact arrays.  One of them is `Values`, which "stores the coefficient values of the non-zeros."  So yes, according to an Eigen tutorial, that *is* a documented behaviour of the storage layout.  And why `InnerIterator` can be implemented efficiently.  So all you need is `&Values[0]` and a length or end-pointer and you're all set, just like for a `std::vector<>`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change every entry and your matrix is in compressed form, you can use the [`.coeffs()`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseCompressedBase.html#a7cf299e08d2a4f6d6869e631e51b12fe) member function:

```
smat.coeffs() = value;
```

Iterating over individual columns would be a bit more difficult, but you can find out the start of each column by looking at `smat.outerIndexPtr()[col]` (the start of `col+1` is the end of `col`).